# Credit Card limit is in range

Tags: paypal, authorize.net

Using Authorize.net SIM API, or Paypal NVP - Is there a way to:

1.accept a credit card
2.check to see if its valid
3.get a return back notifying me that the card can handel the purchase amount.
4.do no transaction

Im looking for terminology or API methods to look up.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's called an Authorization Only or Auth Only. With Authorize.Net you would use their AIM API for this.